# I want data with a particular date duration.my database in sql

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL database in which I have a column with DataType DateTime. Now I want data  with a particular date duration . For example, I want data from 01/09/2012 to 10/09/2012, is there any way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but if you are trying to put in a date, make the column a date column.

Comment: Pls define the DBMS, what do you use!

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)

Comment: next time simple add the tag or retag in case you forgot to add it when asked the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Date >= '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND Date < '2012-09-11 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I am using the following query                                   SELECT * FROM mytablename   where   CreatedDate between  '2012-09-01' and '2012-09-10'. But i got only datas from  '2012-09-01' to '2012-09-09. i did not get the data of '2012-09-10'

Comment: then change the 2012-09-10 to 2012-09-11

Comment: i am selecting the from date and to date from an asp Calendar Extender which is attached to a text box. Then i pass the selected dates to my query

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that strips the time from a DateTime first. I've called mine dbo.DateOf

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateOf](
    @DateAndTime DateTime
)
RETURNS DateTime
AS
begin
    RETURN Cast(FLOOR(Cast(@DateAndTime as Float)) as DateTime)
end
```

Now you'll be able to do a query like this and get results from Datetime columns that include times - and that make sense to humans

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
where dbo.Dateof(datecolumn) >= '2012-09-01' and dbo.DateOf(datecolumn) <= '2012-09-11'
```